# Use Index Seek option to Perform DB snapshot in Debezium

Tags: amazon-kinesis, debezium

I am using Debezium Server to stream data from MySql to Kinesis. Each table has around 1.5million records.

So it is taking a good amount of time for snapshots ( I am getting a rate of 10k records for 5-8mins)
This is so slow and sometimes, Debezium stops and when we restart the instance, It is again taking a snapshot(I am using the when_needed option).

I understand that Debezium is just doing a scan on the table and that is actually taking a good amount of time.

I wrote a python script that takes the max(Id) and then I am doing a batch querying which is effectively using the index on the table and I am able to snapshot all tables (write it to Kinesis) in just 10mins which used to take 9hrs previously.

So right now, I am manually taking a snapshot using my Python script and then starting debezium with the option

```
debezium.source.snapshot.mode=schema_only
```

So what's the best way to increase the snapshot speed without a script as I need to execute this manually whenever debezium stops?
By the way, My Kinesis consists of 4 shards.

Comment: Hi, could you please raise a Jira issue and provide the python script you are using? I'd like to compare the difference. Thanks

Comment: Sure @JiriPechanec I'll provide you the script that I am using. I'll try to simulate the problem I am facing using a repo so that It'll be useful